# Split line into 5 columns

Tags: r

**2016-11-02 09:38:53**, **22822**, **33067**, **6.79**, **Abc, Cedfgh Pqrst 12Abc**

I want to read the above-given data into 5 columns of the data frame. The Last column i.e column 5 can have delimiter character but it should be ignored and consider as one whole string in R.

Hence to put in R terms:

```
data.frame(Var1 = "2016-11-02 09:38:53", Var2 = "22822", Var3 = "33067", Var4 = "6.79", Var5 = "Abc, Cedfgh Pqrst 12Abc")
```

Comment: how do you want the read in data frame to look?

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: @NathanDay - I want the output in the above-given "data.frame" output. File is stored in CSV format and it has 5 columns but one of the rows has more than six delimiter character hence I want to "paste" the extraneous delimiter characters columns into a single column

Comment: `tidyr::separate` is for exactly this purpose if the problem is that the line is in a single column of a `data.frame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just read it as 6 columns and then do:

```
df$var5 <- paste(df$var5, ",", "df$var6")
```

You'll get the `data.frame` as you've shown in expected output.